# want to get data in excel based upon row and column using c#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, excel-2007, excel-interop

> Hi was wondering  through internet for my solution. considering  my excel sheet as array i want to get data based on row and column index, how can i do this. i am not getting a clue to implement this my excel sheet look like below

[image]

> please help in this. i am getting mad of trying different methods.
>
> my requirement is if i give R3,C2 in console ,i should get 4 as my answer.
> i was using Excel.interop for getting this,you can suggest solution by other methods too.
> thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ReadingExcelBasedOnRowColumn
{


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\SaiKiran\Desktop\MyExcl2.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            Console.WriteLine("enter x and y value:");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (xlRange != null)
            {
                int nRows = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                int nCols = xlRange.Columns.Count;
                for (int iRow = 1; iRow <= nRows; iRow++)
                {

                    for (int iCount = 1; iCount <= nCols; iCount++)
                    {   

                        xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[x, y];
                        Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Text);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

i got answer.. after struggling two days

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to call Excel worksheet functions INDEX and MATCH (the basic Excel formula would be =INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH("R3",$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH("C2",$B$1:$D$1,0))

Or you could retrieve the data into an object array, look for C2 in the first row and R3 in the first column.